# SQL aggregation functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given the following table

```
Month        Product  Sales
---------    -------  -----    
January         1      10
January         2      15
February        3      23
March           1      15
```

The query I've used is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM( -- possibly needed for where clause
    SELECT dateadd(month, x.MonthOffset,0) AS mes, x.produto, Sum(x.quantidade) AS vendas
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.data) AS MonthOffset, a.produto, a.quantidade
        FROM (
          SELECT l.*, fc.data FROM LINHAS AS l JOIN FacturaCli AS fc
              ON fc.codigo = l.codigo 
              UNION ALL
          SELECT l.*, ff.dataEmissão FROM LINHAS AS l JOIN FacturaForn AS ff
              ON ff.codigo = l.codigo
        ) AS a
    ) AS x
    GROUP BY MonthOffset, produto
) AS a
```

I would like to get the product with more sales per month.

I'm having trouble doing query that requires a field that must not be in "aggregate group".
Note that the table I provided is a result from a query.

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I can't use temporary variables or `over` clause.
**I wouldn't like to repeat the query that lead me to this table!** But if it is the only way, it's ok.

Expected result:

```
Month        Product  Sales
---------    -------  -----    
January         2      15
February        3      23
March           1      15
```

Comment: Why can't you use an aggregate function? It seems the most sensible option in this context.

Comment: I can use an aggregate function. What I meant is that product must appear in result and the agregrate group is only month for the query i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very tricky solution for your problem.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   mytable a 
       LEFT JOIN mytable b 
              ON a.Month = b.Month
                 AND a.Sales < b.Sales
WHERE  b.Month IS NULL
```

Comment: what if I wouldnt like to reapeat the query ive used? I can't use temporary variables (college requires that)

Comment: @user1279792 which database and version you are using?

Comment: sql server 2008 can't use over too

Comment: @user1279792 - Could you edit your question and include the following?  What the source data looks like.  What you want the results to look like.  What you are allowed to use.  What you're not allowed to use.  And mark it as 'homework' if that's what it is?

Comment: I just can't do anything about the looking of source data. I can however insert the query that lead me to that result

Comment: Post the full query where you need this info.

Comment: I'm accepting you answer, thanks for your help. But would be awesome if it was possible to accomplish the same reulst without repeating the query